# binding qudpsoket on port <1024

Tags: qt, network-programming

I am trying to make a simple dns server using qudpsocket. But when I try to bind the udpsocket
to port 53 I got an error message saying:

```
"The address is protected"  QAbstractSocket::SocketAccessError
```

Program runs fine if I bind it to port>1024.
How can I get access to port 53. I am working on fedora.

Comment: You might want to read a little more about sockets and networking. Then you would know that all ports below 1024 are *reserved*, and need a program with special rights to open.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :)
all you need to do is to use sudo mode to execute files.